# Subscription using websocket through Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, dapp-development, json-rpc, websocket

I am trying to build a dapp which will monitor a particular address balance, and update in case someone send fund (ether) to it.

Instead of polling using call getBalance, I want to take advantage of the relatively new subscription API through WebSocket (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/RPC-PUB-SUB). While I can successfully connect geth using WebSocket, I am struggling to apply the correct filter to the subscription.

Which subscription type should I use? If I use `newHeads` or `newPendingTransactions`, what is the correct filter for this kind of case? BTW, I try "logs" before, it seems that the address parameter is only for contract address but not "regular" address (if you understand what I mean).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, I developed a proof-of-concept. I posted the source in GitHub at https://github.com/AlanL1/Ethereum-FrontEnd

The code that might be useful to you is in transaction.html. I use subscription type `newHeads`, and scan through all the new blocks using `getTransactionFromBlock`. The performance is okay since I am not polling and only react if a new block arrives. Still, if anyone come up with a better solution please share with us.

Comment: I'm trying to run source code, but it gives me an error `Unable to connect to geth` how to connect geth?